# Responsive page in cordova application don't responsive only on real phone

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, responsive

i playing with cordova and angularjs.

I have simple angularjs (based on angular-seed) application that looks like responsive when i test it in pc chrome:

[image]

(screen width same as my phone)

But when i build apk with cordova and install on phone i see huge horizontal scrool:

[image]

I try google it but don't find any clue. What i can do wrong?

If i just take this page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/# and build cordova application i see same horizontal scroll too.

Comment: did you add viewport meta tag?

Comment: Yep, it is presented in angular-seed http://i.imgur.com/Lk5MWQw.png

Answer (score 0):

Add this Meta in index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

Comment: Nope, even with such parameters still horizontal scroll.